# Adding and removing classes for switching tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on a tab design using jQuery to switch between each tab with the slide animation. I'll be the first to admit I'm still learning jQuery but I'm having issues with it jumping rather than a smooth animation and then hiding both tabs. The reason for the delay is to add transitions so it's a smooth motion when it slides up and the second layer comes down. The button active class mimics the timing for a nice look.

Here where I am...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.schedule-tab-links a[href*="#day2"]').click(function(){
    jQuery('.schedule-tab-active').slideToggle('450');
    jQuery('#day2').delay('450').slideToggle('450');
    jQuery('.button-active').delay('450').removeClass('button-active');
    jQuery('.schedule-tab-links a[href*="#day2"]').delay('450').addClass('button-active');
    jQuery('.schedule-tab-active').delay('450').removeClass('schedule-tab-active');
    jQuery('#day2').delay('450').addClass('schedule-tab-active');
  });
});
```

You can see the full code [here](https://codepen.io/askmichaelwood/pen/eyPZWx)

Comment: you could do this with pure css, tutorial here https://onextrapixel.com/creating-content-tabs-with-pure-css/

Comment: you probably need to pass the `duration` or `easing` options to it: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.delay(450)` has no effect on `.addClass()`/`.removeClass()`.

It's ONLY for animations. So you got to use `.setTimeout()` for those.

Then, you want that effect to occur only if that tab is NOT already active, rigth? Else, it slides up and down uselessly.

Here it is updated:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.schedule-tab-links a[href*="#day2"]').click(function(){
    if(!$(this).hasClass("button-active")){
      jQuery('.schedule-tab-active').slideToggle('450');
      jQuery('#day2').delay('450').slideToggle('450');
      setTimeout(function(){
        jQuery('.button-active').removeClass('button-active');
        jQuery('.schedule-tab-links a[href*="#day2"]').addClass('button-active');
        jQuery('.schedule-tab-active').removeClass('schedule-tab-active');
        jQuery('#day2').addClass('schedule-tab-active');
      },450);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.schedule-tab-links {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.schedule-tab-links li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.schedule-tab-links li a {
  padding: .5em;
  background: #e8e8e8;
}
.schedule-tab-links li .button-active {
  background-color: #999;
}
.schedule-tabs {
  padding: 2em; 
  margin-top: 1em;
  display: none;
}
.schedule-tabs.schedule-tab-active {
  display: block;
}
#day1 { background-color: green; }
#day2 { background-color: grey; }
#day3 { background-color: purple; }
#day4 { background-color: orange; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul class="schedule-tab-links">
  <li><a href="#day1" class="button-active">Day 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#day2">Day 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#day3">Day 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#day4">Day 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="day1" class="schedule-tabs schedule-tab-active">Day 1 content goes here</div>
<div id="day2" class="schedule-tabs">Day 2 content goes here</div>
<div id="day3" class="schedule-tabs">Day 3 content goes here</div>
<div id="day4" class="schedule-tabs">Day 4 content goes here</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then, I suggest you use a class too for those tabs... In order to just slightly change that click handler... Instead of duplicating it 4 times or more.

The usage of `$(this)` is a hint...
;)